# Updating table 'previous record' based on their 'new record'

Tags: sql

Is it possible to update previous row **date_end** with the new row **date_start** based on their **machine_id**?

Machine Log:

```
record_id   machine_id  date_start  date_end

1           EQPT-1      10-27-2015
2           EQPT-1      10-28-2015      
3           EQPT-2      10-28-2015
4           EQPT-3      10-28-2015
5           EQPT-3      10-30-2015
6           EQPT-2      10-30-2015


UPDATE machine_log 
SET prev.date_end = new.date_start
WHERE new.machine_id = prev.machine_id
AND new.record_id != prev.record_id
```

Comment: You don't have `tester_id` in table shown. Which rdbms is this for?

Comment: Join table to itself using record_id and machine_Id to find "previous" and "next" row and then update. Exact query depends on DBMS you're using.

Comment: To get better answers, faster, tag the dbms product used!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or newer, you can use [LEAD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) Function:
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f3449/4)

```
UPDATE m
SET m.date_end = lead.endDate
FROM machine_log AS m
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT 
record_id
, LEAD(date_start) OVER (PARTITION BY machine_id ORDER BY date_start) endDate
FROM machine_log
) AS lead ON m.record_id = lead.record_id
```

And if you are using MySQL, you can emulate that with `Limit` like this:
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/96aaf/1)

```
UPDATE machine_log m
INNER JOIN 
(select 
 record_id, 
 (select b.date_start
  from machine_log b
  where b.machine_id=a.machine_id
    and b.date_start > a.date_start
  order by b.date_start Limit 1) as endDate
  from machine_log a
  order by record_id,date_start) lead
ON m.record_id = lead.record_id
SET m.date_end = lead.endDate
;
```

Comment: That requires SQL Server **2012** or newer - those functions aren't available in earlier versions of SQL Server

Comment: @marc_s Thanks, I've updated my answer with a version requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL Server:

```
UPDATE machine_log as next inner join machine_log as prev
on next.machine_id=prev.machine_id
SET prev.date_end = next.date_start
WHERE  next.record_id != prev.record_id
```